# Reduce Macro Time

Tags: excel, vba

I have been worked on a VBA code for past couple of days and everything seems to be working fine till one fine day when I added the below code to it. It marco executed time increased to such an extent that I myself don't when it is going to complete. I have waited for almost 2 hours but it continues to run.

This datasheet that I have is about 15 MB in size and contains around 47,000 rows with 25 columns filled with data. I have running this code to delete rows basis the multiple criteria on Columns "H".

Here is the code. Any help to reduce the runtime is highly appreciated.

Thanks...

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Workbooks("Vivar_Template_Blank.xlsx").Sheets("Main & PCO Working").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, lastRow&, value$
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow5 To 2 Step -1
    value = ws.Cells(i, 8).value
        If Not (value Like "*Supplier Name*" _
            Or value Like "*[PO]Supplier (Common Supplier)*" _
            Or value Like "*ACCENTURE LLP*" _
            Or value Like "*COGNIZANT TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS US CORP*" _
            Or value Like "*INFOSYS LIMITED*" _
            Or value Like "*INFOSYS TECHNOLOGIES LTD*" _
            Or value Like "*INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP DBA IBM CORP*" _
            Or value Like "*MINDTREE LIMITED*" _
            Or value Like "*SYNTEL INC*" _
            Or value Like "*TATA AMERICA INTERNATIONAL CORPORATION*") _
            Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Comment: Probably it is that it has to evaluate 10 If statements for every row. If you could remove the `Like` part I guess it would become more efficient, as the possible number of matches becomes smaller then.

Comment: This should be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, what do you suggest to replace `Like` with...

Comment: [Cross-posted at Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114369/52915)

Comment: I think you need to sanitize the post removing any names of actual companies or people.

Comment: Have you tried loading up all the rows into memory first with `data = ws.Range("H2").Resize(lastRow-1,1).Value2` where `data` is a `Variant`. Then access each value with `data(i,1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting Rows (Row by Row) is slow , try to use Union and delete all Rows by one time.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Workbooks("Vivar_Template_Blank.xlsx").Sheets("Main & PCO Working").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, lastRow&, value$
Dim uRng As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow5 To 2 Step -1 ' !!! maybe lastRow not lastRow5 because there is no value for lastRow5 in your code!!!
    value = ws.Cells(i, 8).value
        If Not (value Like "*Supplier Name*" _
            Or value Like "*[PO]Supplier (Common Supplier)*" _
            Or value Like "*ACCENTURE LLP*" _
            Or value Like "*COGNIZANT TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS US CORP*" _
            Or value Like "*INFOSYS LIMITED*" _
            Or value Like "*INFOSYS TECHNOLOGIES LTD*" _
            Or value Like "*INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP DBA IBM CORP*" _
            Or value Like "*MINDTREE LIMITED*" _
            Or value Like "*SYNTEL INC*" _
            Or value Like "*TATA AMERICA INTERNATIONAL CORPORATION*") _
        Then
            'ws.Rows(i).Delete
              If uRng Is Nothing Then
                Set uRng = ws.Rows(i)
              Else
                Set uRng = Union(uRng, ws.Rows(i))
              End If

        End If
Next

 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Delete

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Answer (score 1):

`Or` is not short-circuited so each `Like` expression will be executed, an alternative to halt on the first match (you don't actually need  `Like` in this case, you can use the more efficient `InStr`):

```
Dim lookup(9) As String

lookup(0) = "Supplier Name"
lookup(1) = "[PO]Supplier (Common Supplier)"
lookup(2) = "ACCENTURE LLP"
lookup(3) = "COGNIZANT TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS US CORP"
lookup(4) = "INFOSYS LIMITED"
lookup(5) = "INFOSYS TECHNOLOGIES LTD"
lookup(6) = "INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP DBA IBM CORP"
lookup(7) = "MINDTREE LIMITED"
lookup(8) = "SYNTEL INC"
lookup(9) = "TATA AMERICA INTERNATIONAL CORPORATION"

For i = lastRow5 To 2 Step -1
    value = ws.Cells(i, 8).value

    For j = 0 To UBound(lookup)
        If InStr(Value, lookup(j)) Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

If any values are empty or there is a large distribution of a constant non-matching value, you should check and exclude them first.

Comment: Thanks for the modified code. I executed this and it ran fine but didn't delete any rows. There is no error to debug but no result as well..

Comment: In that case you will need to step through it to see whats up.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a set of nested if/else constructs such that your logic terminates when the first true condition is encountered.

```
    If Not (value Like "*Supplier Name*") then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    else if value Like "*[PO]Supplier (Common Supplier)*" then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
    else if ...


    End If
```

After you do this, another level of optimization would be to order the 'if' statements from most prevalent to least, thereby reducing the number of expected comparisons.